# absolutely irreducible module

Tags: modules, lie-algebras

If L be lie algebra over F ( F is a field), I want to know what is the definition of absolutely irreducible FL-module? I have confused of several key words related to irreducible modules!? Is there any difference between completely irreducible and absolutely irreducible?

Comment: Is L something special? Like a group or semi group?

Comment: Later it seems like FL might be the enveloping algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I google "absolutely irreducible module" the second hit I get is a passage in Lam's *Exercises in classical ring theory* which explains that an irreducible module $M$ over a $k$ algebra $R$ ($k$ a field) is called absolutely irreducible if $M\otimes_k K$ is irreducible over $R\otimes_k K$ for every extension field K of k.

I would guess the FL part is a semigroup algebra... Hard to tell without more context.

It is commonplace for definitions of modules for associative rings are re-used (where applicable) for modules over Lie algebras. For example, "irreducible module" is used here to mean a module with only trivial modules no matter if the algebra is associative or if it is Lie.  So it seems it would use the same definition for Lie modules.

Comment: what is R in your explanation? you mean M as an R-module?

Comment: @user118746 oops! I dropped it, apparently. Now it's there :)